# What info is really useful in my iptables log and how do I disable the useless bits?

Tags: linux, firewall, monitoring

In my iptables rules files, I entered this at the end:

```
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-ip-options --log-prefix "iptables: "
```

I DROP everything besides `INPUT` for SSH (port 22)

I have a web server and when I try to connect to it through my browser, through a forbidden port number (on purpose), I get something like that in my `iptables.log`

```
Sep 24 14:05:57 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC=yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=59351 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63776 DPT=1999 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 24 14:06:01 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC= yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=63377 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63776 DPT=1999 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 24 14:06:09 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC=yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=55025 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63776 DPT=1999 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 24 14:06:25 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC=yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=54521 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63776 DPT=1999 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 24 14:06:55 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC=yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=100 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=35050 PROTO=TCP SPT=63088 DPT=22 WINDOW=33304 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Sep 24 14:06:55 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC=yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=14076 PROTO=TCP SPT=63088 DPT=22 WINDOW=33264 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Sep 24 14:06:55 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC=yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=5277 PROTO=TCP SPT=63088 DPT=22 WINDOW=33248 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Sep 24 14:06:56 myserver kernel: [xx.xx] iptables: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc SRC=yy.yy.yy.yy DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=100 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=25501 PROTO=TCP SPT=63088 DPT=22 WINDOW=33304 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

As you can see, I typed xx.xx.xx.xx:1999 in my browser, and it tried to connect until it timed out.

**1)** There are many similar lines for just one event. Do you think I need all of them? How would I avoid duplicates?

**2)** The last 4 lines are for my port 22. But since I allow port 22 INPUT for my web server, why are they here?

**3)** Do I need info like `LEN`,`TOS`,`PREC` and others? I'm trying to find a page that explains them one by one, by I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: 1) Browser may try connecting several times, especially if you set DROP, if you set REJECT you will get immediate "connection refused".

Re: 2) Maybe you set -j LOG rule before you allow SSH in, order is significant in  chain.

I recommend [this book](http://www.nostarch.com/firewalls_mr.htm), consider how to analyze and maybe get some statistics from logs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. When I put the -j LOG before the SSH rules, it logs everything I do on the SSH, even though I'm using the right port. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, it is normal, -j LOG just logs packets, it's neither drop or accept them, packets gets logged and continue going through chain until some other rule decide about their destiny ( or finally default policy for that chain ).  Going back to your question, if you -j LOG on the beginning of chain and your host is Internet connected you will get a lot of noise. Question is: why do you logging / what info you want get from your logs ?